# Appending user input to a list as a string

Tags: python

What I am trying to accomplish is, I want to have a function that uses a while loop to check, if there are any not allowed characters.. I am sorry that this a is a beginner question, and I am probably going about it wrong.

“Numbers cannot be used in the middle of a plate; they must come at the end. For example, AAA222 would be an acceptable … vanity plate; AAA22A would not be acceptable. The first number used cannot be a ‘0’.”

“No periods, spaces, or punctuation marks are allowed.”

But you don't have to completely solve that I'd like to continue trying on my own, I just want to know why is it only appending if I enter something that is invalid?

My thought is append it to the list then loop once more to see if includes any the non-allowed characters.

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    exclusions(plate)
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def exclusions(s):
        plate_list = []
        while len(plate_list) < is_valid(s):
           plate_list.append(s)
        print(plate_list)


def is_valid(s):
    return 2 <= len(s) <= 6


main()
```

Anything within 2-6 characters is valid.. so the issue is with the while loop and appending.
So say if something is invalid (Past 6 characters) it appends to the list, and that is what I am trying to solve. I just want it to append the user input, and then I will loop back over to see if it includes any of the non-allowed characters.

Sorry If I am repeating myself, but just trying to be clear as sometimes I guess I am hard to understand what I am trying to accomplish so trying to word my questions better. :)

EDIT: I solved the issue with it only adding invalid inputs, now it only adds inputs that are valid now I just have to figure out how I can loop through a list of invalid characters :)
Simple thing of changing the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

First issue, you are using `list` as a variable name in line `list = []`. This a reserved key word in python so you should not use it as a variable name. Change it so something else.

Second issue, `len(list)` returns `0`, and in python `0` is interpreted as `False`. So, when you enter invalid plate, `is_valid(s)` returns `False`. And your condition in while statement becomes, `False == False`, which is `True`. So, your while statement works only for invalid plate. But when you enter valid plate, `is_valid(s)` returns `True`, so your condition for while statement becomes `False == True`, which is `False`. So, your while loop doesn't work for a valid plate.

Comment: Okay I've changed the variable name to plate_list. and okay that does make sense. Thank you. For the suggestions and the explanation as well!

Comment: I am looking at some more len examples to try and get a better understanding of how to use that method now, once again thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Ah I fixed it by changing the conditional, to < less than the len of the plate_list.

Comment: If the purpose of ```is_valid()``` function is just to check for the length of the ```s```, and that's the only condition for your ```while loop```. I would suggest to remove ```is_valid()``` function and then change your condition in ```while loop``` to ```while 2 <= len(s) <= 6: #then do what you wanted to do with  s, inside while loop```. I guess you won't even need the ```list``` for your current code.

Comment: You don't think so even whenever coming down to removing the other characters that aren't allowed? I was going to create another list that has the none allowed characters and then have the loop make sure the list doesn't contain them.. Let me know if that sounds odd.

Comment: It's upto you how you want to write your program. There is not just one way to write. So, it's your call. But, I would like to focus on another issue with your current modified code, ```len(plate_list) < is_valid(s)```, you are comparing length which is ```int``` with a ```boolean``` value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245313/discussion-between-blue-and-bhusalc-bipin).